# Ecto - how to get `has_many` with specific query

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have an ecto model with `has_many` association. I want to define this association with some query by default.

Like

```
defmodule MyApp.User do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    has_many :comments, MyApp.Comment
  end
end
```

I want to fetch comments which aren't `deleted` (deleted is a boolean field of MyApp.Comment schema, it should be equal to false). What is the way to achieve that?

**My try #1**

I tried to do

```
has_many :comments, Ecto.Query.from(c in MyApp.Comment, where: v.deleted == false)
```

But I got

```
(ArgumentError) association queryable must be a schema or {source, schema}, got: #Ecto.Query
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Ecto doesn't have the concept of scopes like active record does. The closest thing I could suggest would be to create a function in `user.ex` along the lines of `active_comments`.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you have `Post` and `Comment` models, you can find the non-deleted comments with the help of `Ecto.Query` and then `Ecto.Repo`.

```
query = from c in Comment,
        where c.deleted == false,
        select: c

comments = MyApp.Repo.all(query) # This will give you all the non-deleted comments
```

Also, You may want the following query in you application.

```
alias MyApp.{Post,Comment}

query = from p in Post,
        join: c in assoc(p, :comments),
        where: c.deleted == false,
        select: {p, c} # for comments only - just select: c.

Blog.Repo.all(query)
```

Comment: I know that, thanks. But how can I specify this kind of associations in the schema block? That's the question

Comment: oh! Generally I create a method in models and then use it in controller action. Which is clear and easy to compose.
This would be interesting but I've never seen anyone doing something like this yet.